# Limit with $\cos$ and powers

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I solve: $$\lim_{x\to 0} (\cos 3x)^{1/ x^2}$$

I don't think I can use L'hopital because of the power? not really sure how I would rewrite this so that it is $f(x)/g(x)$ where $\lim f'(x) = 0$ and $\lim g'(x) =0$.

So I tried the following:

$$\cos(3x)^{1/x^2} =\cos(3x)^{x^{-2}}$$

Fill $0$ in: $\cos(0)^{0^2}$

$\cos(0) = 1$ and $0^{2} = 0$  which should make $1^0$ which is $1$?

I feel like I did something completely wrong as wolframalpha gives a completely different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I'd do it:
(no Taylor expansion or $o$ order, just pure old brute force with L'hopitals rule)

$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} (\cos (3x))^{1/x^2} =
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} e^{x^{-2} \ln (\cos (3x))} =
e^{\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x^{-2} \ln (\cos (3x))}
$

So now let's observe:

$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x^{-2} \ln (\cos (3x)) =
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac {\ln (\cos (3x))} {x^2} 
$

Applying L'hopitals rule twice

$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0}  \frac { -  \frac {3 \sin (3x)}{\cos (3x)}} {2x} =
\lim\limits_{x \to 0}  -  \frac {3 \tan (3x) } {2x} =
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac {-9} 2 \sec^2 (3x) = \frac {-9} 2
$

So to conclude:

$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} (\cos (3x))^{1/x^2} =
e^{\lim\limits_{x \to 0} (x^{-2}) \ln (\cos (3x))} =
e^{ \frac {-9} 2}
$

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely what I was looking for! solving this with l'hopital :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** First write $$(\cos 3x)^{1/x^2} = e^{\frac{1}{x^2}\ln (\cos 3x) }$$

Now you may use L'Hospital for $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln (\cos 3x)}{x^2}$$

and remember that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$

Comment: I cannot use this shortcut seeing that my problem is cos(3x) and not cos(x) right?

Comment: Yes you can, only thing that changes is a constant once you use the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$\ln (\cos 3x)^{1/x^2} = \frac{1}{x^2}\ln \cos 3x = \frac{1}{x^2}\ln\left(1 - \frac{9x^2}{2} + o(x^2)\right) = \frac{1}{x^2}\left(-\frac{9x^2}{2} + o(x^2)\right)$$
$$ = -\frac{9}{2} + o(1)$$

we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \ln(\cos 3x)^{1/x^2} = -\frac{9}{2}$$

and thus

$$\lim_{x\to 0} (\cos 3x)^{1/x^2} = e^{-9/2}.$$

Comment: what are these o's? and does this change much seeing as I had to solve for cos(3x) and not cos(x)

Comment: @SidneyJacobs the little $o$'s are coming from Taylor expansions.  We say $f(x) = o(g(x))$ as $x \to 0$ if $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)/g(x) = 0$. So having $f(x) = o(1)$ means $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: @SidneyJacobs just a few changes are made when dealing with $\cos 3x$.